# cut audio data in the stream with java

Tags: java, audio

i know how to read bytes from file and save, but how can i read seconds from an audio file and save in a new file? is there any method for this?how many bytes contains 1 second?maybe it sounds stupied but i have no idea.

p.s. i want to record only 20 seconds from an audio file and save this 20 seconds to another file.. i know how to write to a new file, but how to write only some part(20 seconds) of an audio file

thx in advance
roni

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the format you are using for capturing the audio stream. For example if your are using raw (uncompressed) audio, 16 bits per sample, stereo, and [44Khz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/44,100_Hz) (which means 44100 samples per second), then you need to store 2*(16/8)*44100 bytes per second. Additionally, if you want to write some kind of standard file that other applications can read, you will need to decide on a container format. For raw (uncompressed) audio, [Microsoft wave files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) are commonly used, and it will  require you to write a header with some metadata at the begining of your file.

Update:

You can try using [AudioFileWriter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/spi/AudioFileWriter.html).