# I want to develop an mp3 cutter in android how can in implement this for mp3

Tags: android, mp3

I am able to play `mp3` from `sd card` with the help of `Media player` object. But now want to cut the mp3 .

```
mp.reset();
mp.setDataSource(MEDIA_PATH + path);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

I searched on google but didn't get a proper solution. Can anyone please help?

Comment: some useful links
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775232/trimming-audio-mp3-or-wav-file
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941120/cut-audio-data-in-the-stream-with-java
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21228334/how-to-turn-the-position-of-relativelayout-when-the-orientation-of-screen-change